# how to find table row with specific attr id

Tags: html, jquery

I have an onclick function in my HTML: `<td onclick showDep(this, <?= $id;?>) >`

I would like to change the background of the relative table row that has a specific ID, e.g. clicking on first row function I want to go to the row that has `id="4"`.

```js
function showDep(t, id) {
  $(t).closest('tr').each(function() {
    $.find('.rowDep').attr('id' = id).css({
      'background': 'gray'
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td onclick="showDep(this, $<?= $id;?>)"><b>Movements</b> </td>
</tr>
<tr class=" rowDep " id="26 ">
  <td>Landing</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowDep " id="8 ">
  <td><input type="time " class="landing " value="<?=$v[ 'landing'];?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Block</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowDep" id="4">
  <td><input type="time" class="block" value="<?=$v['block'];?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button onclick="sendMVT(this, <?=$id;?>)" class="inpBtnSave" type="button">MVT</button> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you not know how to access an element by ID, or how to change its background?  If you have attempted to solve this, how, and what issue(s) are you having with it?

Comment: Where is `.rowDep` - it is not in your example - Also - this doesn't need the `closest` or `each` functions - you are looking for an id - that is not duplicated, so just `$('#'+id)`

Comment: I've added the class .rowDep and I'll try your solution ad let you know

Comment: FYI, you were missing closing quotes on your `onclick` attribute in the first row. Also, `('id' = id)` is invalid syntax. It should be `('id', id)`.

Comment: And you should be using [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) rather than inline event attributes. Keep your markup clean. In jQuery this would be [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/), etc.

Comment: IDs in an HTML document must be unique. Having the same `id` on multiple elements is an error. Also, the `id` should start with a letter. [id - HTML: HyperText Markup Language | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: If your `id="26"` is *not* a DOM identifier (hint: it's not) then you should use `data-id="26"` instead.   Finding by data uses `[ ]`, eg `$(".rowDep[data-id='4']").css({ 'background': 'gray' })`

Comment: Relevant: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/